# How to transfer data between spring flows?

Tags: java, spring

I have set of data that is not necessary to store in database.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity extends Entity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7807480090652491368L;
    @Transient
    private Set<Long> productsIds = new LinkedHashSet<Long>();
}
```

Also, I have two flows: **cabinet**:

```
<secured attributes="ROLE_USER" />

<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="userService.loadUserEntityByEmail(currentUser.name)"
        result="flowScope.user" />
</on-start>

<view-state id="cabinet" view="main.xhtml">
    <transitions...
</view-state>

<view-state id="cart" view="cart.xhtml">
    <transitions...
</view-state>

<end-states...
```

**content**:

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate
        expression="currentUser!= null ? userService.loadUserEntityByEmail(currentUser.name) : null"
        result="flowScope.user">
    </evaluate>
</on-start>

<view-state id="content" view="content.xhtml">
    <transitions...
</view-state>

<end-states...
```

I need to transfer data `Set<Long> productsIds` from `content` to `cabinet` (and vice versa, but it is not main).

Also I use JSF 2.1, javascript, Servlet. Maybe it will be easier to transfer data with their help

Comment: What is the meaning of the IDs in this set? (And why aren't you using a `Set<Product>`?)

Comment: @chrylis , there is only id of product (34, 58, 45...). There aren't whole product because I cannot/don't know how to paste into `Set` object `Product` with help of javascript